Are BFS and DFS the same and just the Monad is different?
I wrote a tail-recursive BFS in Scala:
import scala.collection.mutable

/** Do BFS from start and return the smallest distance to end (None if not connected) */
def bfs[A](start: A, end: A, neighbors: A => Seq[A]): Option[Int] = {
  val seen = mutable.Set(start)

  @annotation.tailrec
  def search(curr: Seq[A], dist: Int): Option[Int] =
    if seen(end) then Some(dist)
    else if curr.isEmpty then None
    else search(curr.flatMap(neighbors).filter(seen.add), dist + 1)

  search(curr = Seq(start), dist = 0)
}

The search function operates recursively at each depth from start.
Example usage:
val graph = Map(
  1 -> Seq(2, 3),
  2 -> Seq(4),
  3 -> Seq(4),
  4 -> Seq(5)
)

val dist = bfs(start = 1, end = 5, neighbors = graph)
println(dist)

Now, I realized this looks eerily similar to the recursive DFS:
def dfs[A](start: A, end: A, neighbors: A => Seq[A]): Option[Int] = {
  val seen = mutable.Set(start)

  def search(curr: A, dist: Int): Option[Int] =
    if seen(end) then Some(dist)
    else neighbors(curr).filter(seen.add).flatMap(search(_, dist + 1)).minOption

  search(curr = start, dist = 0)
}

Can we somehow combine these two? Here's what I tried:
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

def search[F[_]: Monad, A](start: A, end: A, neighbours: A => Seq[A]): Option[Int] = {
  val seen = mutable.Set(start)

  def doSearch(curr: F[A], dist: Int): Option[Int] =
    if seen(end) then Some(dist) 
    else curr.flatMap(neighbours).filter(seen.add).flatMap(doSearch(_, dist + 1)).minOption
  
  doSearch(curr = Monad[F].pure(start), dist = 0)
}

def bfs[A](start: A, end: A, neighbours: A => Seq[A]): Option[Int] = search[List, A](start, end, neighbours)
def dfs[A](start: A, end: A, neighbours: A => Seq[A]): Option[Int] = search[Id, A](start, end, neighbours)

Intuitively kinda makes sense since BFS = look at all neighbors at a time (hence List) and DFS = look at 1 neighbor at a time (hence Id)
Questions:

I could not quite make it compile. What am I doing wrong? Is Monad the least powerful abstraction here to use? Maybe Traverse?
Is this even a correct approach? I think I am onto something but I did not find any literature out there that talks about BFS/DFS this way i.e. BFS = List monad and DFS = Id monad instead of FIFO vs. LIFO
Any way we can make doSearch tail recursive (e.g. using scala.util.control.TailCalls or tailRecM)?


I'm not sure it's even a  BFS anymore. You are looking at every visited vertex at every step. This makes the whole business at least O(v^2).

No, it looks at a vertex atmost once. See: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DllQQD4JQM2MOH1SepCbfg

I just tried a Leetcode problem using recursive BFS: https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-knight-moves/submissions/1280565017
It is the fastest scala solution submitted. This would time out otherwise.

You are right, it replaces the current set and doesn't add to it as I thought.

Yeah I am 100% sure the BFS and DFS part is fine. But I might be barking up the wrong tree (or the wrong typeclass) when I try to combine them into a single util

BFS=List works for you because neigbours are also a list, so you can flatten a list of lists. But DFS=Id won't work, because neigbours are still a list and you cannot flatten an Id[List[_]].

@n.m.couldbeanAI: Ah good point. Maybe Traverse?
